# Excel to sql, using delimiter (;) - postgres/pgadmin

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I am trying to import an excel file to postgresql using pgadmin but faced many issues here.

My original data is an excel format and the data values include many comma. So I convert excel file into csv format using delimiter (;). I could do so by unchecking  "use system separators" option in excel. (This will make changes in numeric values. For example, 40.2 becomes 40,2)

When I try to import this csv file in pgadmin I got numerous errors due to data type, numeric. The pgadmin do not consider 40,2 as a numeric value. Interestingly, I could do similar thing with other dataset when I convert the other data set (txt -> csv (;)-> then import to pgadmin). It worked!
However, if I try with my data it did not work.
 (excel -> txt -> csv (;) -XX-> pgadmin).

Any idea how I can address this? Maybe I would like to know other ways to generate semicolon-csv files from excel.

Comment: This looks like it's Postgres specific and not MySQL, right?

Comment: @tadman I also tried with workbench and no row is added.

Comment: Can you please share some sample file.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with excel to csv to use after a python script to fill a database, and if you generate the csv file from windows I noticed 2 things:

1. the return line is not a char `'\n'` but `\r\n`
2. excel add some invisible char at the begin of the file.csv

hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

Use `psql` and its `\copy` command:

```
\copy mytable FROM 'mytable.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER ';')
```

`COPY` won't be able to handle “`,`” as a decimal separator, make sure it is “`.`”.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can export excel to csv file directly inside excel if you use Excel 2016. Choose "Export" -> Other File Types -> "CSV （Comma delimited) (*.csv)".

I think excel will put quote (") around your text column which includes "," automatically. Then you can import CSV file to data base using the normal approach.